# Visual Studio 2019 event handling issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2019 I'm creating a program that converts different units of measurements, what it does is if I put in a number for feet it calculates the rest of units with the number used in feet. In my program the first four functions work but the application freezes when I try to input the last four.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConversionLenUnit
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void txtMeter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtMillimeter.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtMeter.Text) * 1000}";
            txtCentimeter.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtMeter.Text) * 100}";
            txtKilometer.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtMeter.Text) / 1000}";
            txtInch.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtMeter.Text) * 39.37}";
            txtYard.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtMeter.Text) * 1.0936}";
            txtFoot.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtMeter.Text) * 3.28}";
            txtMile.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtMeter.Text) * 0.00062137}";
        }

        private void txtMillimeter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtMeter.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtMillimeter.Text) / 1000}";
            txtCentimeter.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtMillimeter.Text)/ 10}";
            txtKilometer.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtMillimeter.Text) / 1000000}";
            txtInch.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtMillimeter.Text) / 25.4}";
            txtYard.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtMillimeter.Text) / 914}";
            txtFoot.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtMillimeter.Text) / 305}";
            txtMile.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtMillimeter.Text) * 0.00000062137}";
        }

        private void txtCentimeter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtMeter.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtCentimeter.Text) / 100}";
            txtMillimeter.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtCentimeter.Text) * 10}";
            txtKilometer.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtCentimeter.Text) / 100000}";
            txtInch.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtCentimeter.Text) / 2.54}";
            txtYard.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtCentimeter.Text) / 91.44}";
            txtFoot.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtCentimeter.Text) / 30.48}";
            txtMile.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtCentimeter.Text) / 160934}";
        }

        private void txtKilometer_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtMeter.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtKilometer.Text) * 1000}";
            txtMillimeter.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtKilometer.Text) / 0.000001}";
            txtCentimeter.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtKilometer.Text) * 100000}";
            txtInch.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtKilometer.Text) * 39370}";
            txtYard.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtKilometer.Text) * 1094}";
            txtFoot.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtKilometer.Text) * 3281}";
            txtMile.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtKilometer.Text) / 1.609}";
        }

        private void txtInch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //txtMeter.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtInch.Text) / 39.37}";
            //txtMillimeter.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtInch.Text) * 25.4}";
            //txtCentimeter.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtInch.Text) * 2.54}";
            //txtKilometer.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtInch.Text) / 39370}";
            //txtYard.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtInch.Text) / 36}";
            //txtFoot.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtInch.Text) / 12}";
            //txtMile.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtInch.Text) / 63360}";
        }

        private void txtYard_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //txtMeter.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtYard.Text) / 1.094}";
            //txtMillimeter.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtYard.Text) * 914}";
            //txtCentimeter.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtYard.Text) * 91.44}";
            //txtKilometer.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtYard.Text) / 1094}";
            //txtInch.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtYard.Text) * 36}";
            //txtFoot.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtYard.Text) * 3}";
            //txtMile.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtYard.Text) / 1760}";
        }

        private void txtFoot_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //txtMeter.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtFoot.Text) / 3.281}";
            //txtMillimeter.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtFoot.Text) * 305}";
            //txtCentimeter.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtFoot.Text) * 30.48}";
            //txtKilometer.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtFoot.Text) / 3281}";
            //txtInch.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtFoot.Text) * 12}";
            //txtYard.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtFoot.Text) / 3}";
            //txtMile.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtFoot.Text) / 5280}";
        }

        private void txtMile_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //txtMeter.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtMile.Text) * 1609}";
            //txtMillimeter.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtMile.Text) * 1609344}";
            //txtCentimeter.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtMile.Text) * 160934}";
            //txtKilometer.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtMile.Text) * 1.609}";
            //txtInch.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtMile.Text) * 63360}";
            //txtYard.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtMile.Text) * 1760}";
            //txtFoot.Text = $"{double.Parse(txtMile.Text) * 5280}";
        }
    }
}
```

[image: This is the output that I want]

Comment: If you set up two event handlers with a pattern like: "When A changes, change B". and "When B changes, change A".  That is essentially an endless loop.

Comment: OT suggested cleanup: use double.Parse once (with error checking) per handler, then use that result in the next lines

Comment: Important aspect of this is that it's likely the last couple of digit(s) of the calculation that are flip-flopping due to floating point precision.  If the text doesn't change, it doesn't actually trigger the TextChanged event.  You could add some log messages to confirm this.

Comment: For future reference, please read [ask] and [mcve] before you post another question to this site. Your question is essentially a duplicate of others already here (the marked duplicate is for WPF, but the same principles still apply to Winforms), but the question itself is very poor quality. The community invests significant effort in answering questions; people who post questions should invest at least as much effort in writing them.

Answer (score 1):

What is undoubtedly happening is that you are causing another event to fire while still handling the first event, then it causes yet another event to fire in an endless loop.  You should be able to see this in the debugger.

The solution is to add a boolean to your class that keeps track if you are in the midst of handling an event.  Each event handler needs to do an early `return` if that boolean is true.

After checking if it's `true`, set it to `true`, do all the work of the event handler, then set it to `false` at the end.

For example,

```
private bool changing = false;

private void txtMeter_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (changing) return;

   changing = true;

   // do all the work

   changing = false;
}
```